# Temporarily Number Rows to Group by in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a temporary column that gives each set of five results a number so that I can group by.. I am having a lot of trouble trying to work out how to do this.

I don't want to take any criteria into account, I want the sql to count the first five results it sees as GroupNumber 1 and the next five results as GroupNumber2 and so on..

Here is some sample data -

```
Fruits  Ordered  Date
Orange  4        2015-05-01 00:01:01
Orange  2        2015-05-01 00:01:05
Orange  20       2015-05-01 15:15:00
Apple   30       2015-05-02 16:20:01
Apple   40       2015-05-02 17:01:27 
Apple   24       2015-05-02 21:01:33  
Apple   19       2015-05-02 18:01:01  
Apple   22       2015-05-02 19:00:05
```

Now, I know i could group this data by casting the DATETIME column to a DATE column, but this isn't what I specifically need, I don't want to bring date into it if possible.

The desired result before GROUP BY would be like this - -

```
Fruits  Ordered  Date                GroupNumber
Orange  4        2015-05-01 00:01:01 1
Orange  2        2015-05-01 00:01:05 1
Orange  20       2015-05-01 15:15:00 1
Apple   30       2015-05-02 16:20:01 1
Apple   40       2015-05-02 17:01:27 1
Apple   24       2015-05-02 21:01:33 2 
Apple   19       2015-05-02 18:01:01 2
Apple   22       2015-05-02 19:00:02 2
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Result is before group by, sorry

Comment: According to your criteria `{Apple,30}` and `{Apple,40}` should be in GroupNumber 1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using variables:

```
select s.*,
       floor( ((@rn := @rn + 1) - 1) / 5) as group_number
from sample s cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by date;
```

Comment: Don't know if you can advise on this, although the query works a treat, I get 0-19 in row numbers so that I can group by them, but If I apply a sum in the query, it seems to produce more row numbers - 0-24 to be exact, do you know why this would happen at all?

Comment: @Dan . . . Perhaps you should ask another question.  A SQL Fiddle would be a great way to show this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Give a `rownumber` to each row by order by date. Then divide the rownumber by 5 and use the `ceiling` function.

**Query**

```
select t.Fruits,t.Ordered,t.`Date`,
ceiling((t.rn)/5) as Group_Number
from
(
   select f.*, 
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rn
   from fruits f, 
   (select @rownum := 0) r
   order by f.`Date`
)t;
```

[Fiddle demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f28/16)